# filter search output before writing to text file

Tags: batch-file

For batch script, i am trying to grep some searches before saving it to a text file, but there are some search entries which are unwanted.
Command i use to search and save into text2.txt:

```
grep -nri !line! --colour --include=*.{c,h} >> text2.txt
```

is it possible to filter the output before i write to the file?

Stuff that i want to filter before writing to the file:

```
type text.txt | findstr /I "#include # include" | findstr /V "examples DELIVERY_REL #ifndef #define" > text2.txt

DELIVERY_REL/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxxxxx.h:139:#ifndef _xxxxxx_h_
/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxxxxx.h:32:#include "../../xxxx/xxxxxxxx.h"
/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/xxxxxxx.h:26:#include "../../xxxxxx/xxxxxxx.h"
```

Comment: findstr does not extract text for you. You need to use a for loop to extract substrings from strings. You would need to show me the actual input and expected output.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard due to some confidential stuff i cannot show the output. But there is no way to grep -nri !line! --colour --include=*.{c,h} {insert some filter here before i write to file?}>> text2.txt

Comment: Just mask the confidential stuff with other wording. As long as the full formats remain.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard i have included a example, i just want to store the last 2 lines with the dependencies on header file in the !line! variable

Comment: Ok, but the current `findstr` you have extracts the full strings already, which portion from the strings do you still want to extract?